# Create .tfvars file using Bash from Jenkins pipeline

Tags: bash, jenkins, terraform

i'm trying to create ".tfvars" file on the fly using Bash script with Jenkins parameters as arguments, here is what I did already :

**Jenkins pipeline file**

```
pipeline {
    agent { label "${params.environment}_slave" }
    
    parameters {
        string(name: 'branch', defaultValue:"main")
        choice(name: 'environment',choices: ['nonprod','prod'],description:'Describe where you want this pipeline to run')
        booleanParam(name: 'bool', defaultValue:"false")
        string(name: 'string', defaultValue:"value")
        text(name: 'blabla', defaultValue:'''test\test-api\nmlflow''')
        string(name: 'int', defaultValue:"1234")
    }

    environment {
        SCM_URL = "https://my_git/my_repo"

    }
    
    stages {
        stage("Test if prerequisites have been executed") {
            steps {
                git branch: "$params.branch" ,url: "${SCM_URL}"
                    sh "chmod +x -R ${env.WORKSPACE}"
                    sh "./script.sh \"${params}\""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Bash script :**

```
    params=$1
    modified=${params:1:-1}    
    res=$(echo $modified | sed 's/:/=/g')
    
    while IFS='=' read -r key value; do
        array["$key"]="$value"
    done <<< "$res"
    
    for key in "${!array[@]}"; do
        echo "$key=${array[$key]}" >> terraforms.tfvars;
    done
printf "terraforms.tfvars ======== \n"
cat terraforms.tfvars
```

and when I run everything in Jenkins, here is the result :

```
+ chmod +x -R /home/jenkins/workspace/my_repo
[Pipeline] sh
+ ./script.sh '[environment:nonprod, bool:false, string:value, blabla:test
test-api
mlflow, branch:main, int:1234]'
terraforms.tfvars ======== 
0=nonprod, bool=false, string=value, blabla=test test-api mlflow, branch=main, int=1234
```

I don't understand why I have `0=nonprod` instead of `environment=nonprod`

any ideas ? or suggestions about the whole thing ?

thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had `0=nonprod` because I didn't instantiate the array first :

```
declare -A array
```